# WebDriver Sampler script in JMeter to populate a input type "File" during file upload scenario

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, webdriver, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have tried the below script.. but no luck..

var Import = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//input[@id=\'fileUpload\']'));
Import.click();
Import.sendKeys(['D:\Spreadsheets\WL_SpreadsheetImport.xlsx']);

Error Log:
2020-05-14 14:57:29,740 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't call `Import.click();` otherwise system modal file upload dialog will open and it is not controllable by Selenium
2. You need to escape the backslash with another backslash like:

   ```
   Import.sendKeys(['D:\\Spreadsheets\\WL_SpreadsheetImport.xlsx']);
   ```

   or just use single forward slashes:

   ```
   Import.sendKeys(['D:/Spreadsheets/WL_SpreadsheetImport.xlsx']);
   ```

More information:

- [How to Upload & Download a File using Selenium Webdriver](https://www.guru99.com/upload-download-file-selenium-webdriver.html)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)